# updating point instead of comma inside nvarchar(255) column in which there are numbers

Tags: sql-server, types

i would like to understand how to:

1) substitute comma ',' with point '.' inside a nvarchar(255) column in an update statement with numbers that are with the same length (except 0 that remains 0) and are like this one

0,123456

2) convert this column in a decimal(9,6) column

Comment: I tried with CAST CONVERT PARSE AND REPLACE but no one is working

Comment: Have you had a look at `REPLACE` and `CAST`/`CONVERT`? If you have, what did you try, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with TRY_CONVERT and replace.

```
select *
    , try_convert(decimal(9,6), replace(x.n, ',', '.'))
from 
(values('0,123456'))x(n)
```